# Share java and android sdk versions in intellij

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea

We have IntelliJ project and module files checked into version control. They great, but if we switch java or android sdks, everyone needs to do something on their own machine (update the sdk, add it to IntelliJ, etc.).

I found http://leolabs.org/blog/making-intellij-portable/, which explains how to set up configuration paths in IntelliJ, which allows us to share things like SDKs. My current plan is to follow that guide and check the IntelliJ install directory into our version control so everyone can run it from there, and it will have sdks all set up.

The problem I see with this technique is then other options are shared as well. That's great for coding style (though you can make coding style project specific, so that's not a real win), but not as good for things like visible white-space.

So my question is: Is there a more granular way to share java and android SDKs and have IntelliJ correctly point to them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDKs and Global Libraries are referenced in the project files by names, like `1.7` for Java or  `Android 4.2.2 Platform` for Android SDK.

The easiest solution is to agree about the common names for the SDKs and ask all the developers to configure the SDKs using these names (needs to be done only once and when you have to switch to the new major version of the SDK).

This configuration allows the developers to have actual SDK installations in different locations and is also OS independent.

If you decide to share global IDE configuration files (like `jdk.table.xml`), all the team members will need to have SDKs installed in the same place and it will fail between different operating systems.

Comment: Operating systems are irrelevant to us (famous last words, but true for now). In our case, we have to do updates more often than many because we use an internal sdk add-on, which makes this problem worse than for most groups.

Comment: It's your choice how to share the settings, if you want automatic configuration of the SDKs and the SDKs are in the same place on all the machine, set up some custom sync for the `jdk.table.xml` file in the [idea.config.path](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108)`\options` directory.

Comment: That's a good idea actually. Just syncing jdk.table.xml (as part of a setup script or whatever).

Comment: Can you maybe confirm that there's been a change in the default naming of the Android platforms from IntelliJ version 12 to version 13? For version 12 a name like "Android 4.0 Platform" is typical, while for version 13 a name like "Android API 14 Platform" is typical, right?